# c++ .net HTML parser

Tags: html, parsing, visual-c++

Is there a library to parse a HTML response in in C++ .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any .NET-library in C++/CLI. So take a look at these two threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653357/html-parsing-libraries-for-net); [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c))

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/Community/SgmlReader), which creates an XMLdocument from HTML or SGML input, which then you can easily handle. It does handle malformed HTML, too. Don't know if it's C++, but you can surely use it from your code by referencing the assembly.