# How can I select or capture multiple HTML tags using regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, web-scraping

To get a certain HTML tag and its contents from a html document I am using regex -

html -

```
<div id="abc">content</div>
<a class="anchorclass">content</a>
<table id="table1">content</table>
<div id="div2">content</div>
<a class="anchorclass2">content</a>
<div class="divclass">content</div>
```

regex

```
    /<div id="abc"[\s\S]*?<\/div>/
```

which returns precisely this particular `div` contents (div with id="abc").

I want to capture multiple html elements from above with a single regex expression, how can I do that ? is there a way to concatenate conditions or is there any "and" operator to select multiple html tags ?

I want to write a single regex expression which selects -

1. div with id="abc"
2. a with class="anchorclass"
3. div with class="divclass"

from above html, how would that be ?

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this. Use an [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653357/) like HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score -1):

`HTML` tags with attributes, here is my solution to deal with that:

```
// <TAG(.*?)>(.*?)</TAG>
// Example
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<h1(.*?)>(.*?)</h1>");
var m = regex.Match("Hello <h1 style='color: red;'>World</h1> !!");
Console.Write(m.Groups[2].Value); // will print -> World
```

Comment: I am using this already, I want to know how can I select multiple html tags in a single regex expression for example both a div with id=yourID and a span with id=yoursecondID. Please take a look at the edited version of my question.

Answer (score -1):

If you already know the class/id you can use the following:

```js
yourHtml = '<html><bod><a id="yourID">Some more text</a><div id="yourID">Some text here</div></body></html>'

regex = /<(?:div|a) id="(?:abc|anchorclass|divclass)">(.*?)<\/(?:div|a)>/g

while((result = regex.exec(yourHtml)) !== null) {
    console.log(result[1]);
}
```

(?:div|a) matches divs and links. Just add anything you like.

But I would not recommend using regex for this! It is way to error-prone and no fun at all when debugging. Instead I would propose parsing the html as a whole an then search it.

```js
yourHtml = '<html><bod><div id="yourID">Some text here</div></body></html>'

parser = new DOMParser();
parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(yourHtml,"text/html");

console.log(parsedHtml.getElementById("yourID").innerText)
```

This way you will be able to use any of the standard js functions on `parsedHtml` without creating a new regex each time. This is a way more elegant solution.

Comment: "let regex = /<div id="yourID">(.*?)<\/div>/"
I am using this already, I want to know how can I select multiple html tags in a single regex expression for example both a div with id=yourID and a span with id=yoursecondID.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope that fits your needs. But I would really recommend using the `DOMParser`. Its a better solution in every way.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have just one doubt, isnt that operator | is an OR operator ? are you sure that this would get ALL of the html tags I will specify in the regex ? or this would pick up just ANY SINGLE one of them ?

Comment: The regex itsself matches every one, but only one at a time. `regex.exec()` returns an iterator for all of them. So the loop indeed goes over every single one of them.